# how to get Full text using Tweepy

Tags: python-3.x, api, twitter, tweepy

I am new to python and i'm using [This](https://github.com/agalea91/twitter_search) script to get tweets. But the problem is that it is not giving full Text.Instead it is giving me URL of tweet.

output
'

> "text": "@Damien85901071 @Loic_23 @EdwinZeTwiter @Christo33332 @lequipedusoir @Cristiano @RealMadrid_FR @realfrance_fr\u2026 '  [ShortenURL](https://twitter.com/i/web/status/938907715144892417)",

what changes i need to make in this script to get full text ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into [Twitter's `tweet_mode=extended` option](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/tweet-updates) and the places in the Python code where you might need to add that to the script.